# How do I combine multiple rows in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following nodes:

```
p:Person
s:Skill
```

And the relationship is: `(p)-[KNOWS]-(s)`.

My query is:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:KNOWS]->(s:Skill) 
WHERE p.Name=~'Julie.*' 
RETURN (p.Name),(s.Name)
```

The Output is:

```
╒════════════╤══════════════════════════════╕
│(p.Name)    │(s.Name)                      │
╞════════════╪══════════════════════════════╡
│Julie Rocha │Knowledge Management          |
├────────────┼──────────────────────────────┤
│Julie Rocha │MongoDB                       │
└────────────┴──────────────────────────────┘
```

The Desired Output is:

```
╒════════════╤══════════════════════════════╕
│(p.Name)    │(s.Name)                      │
╞════════════╪══════════════════════════════╡
│Julie Rocha │Knowledge Management, MongoDB |
└────────────┴──────────────────────────────┘
```

How can I accomplish this? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`collect()`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/cypher/#aggregation-collect):

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:KNOWS]->(s:Skill) 
WHERE p.Name =~ 'Julie.*' 
RETURN p.Name, collect(s.Name) AS skill
```

In the result, the `skill` attribute will be a [list](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/cypher/#syntax-lists).

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I need :)