# string aggregation in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, aggregate-functions

I need an equivalent of Postgres `string_agg`, Oracle `listagg` or MySQL `group_concat` in Cypher. My Cypher query is a stored procedure returning stream of strings (in following minimized example replaced by collection unwind). As a result, I want to get single string with concatenation of all strings.

Example:

```
UNWIND ['first','second','third'] as c
RETURN collect(c)
```

Actual result (of list type):

```
["first", "second", "third"]
```

Expected result (of String type):

```
"firstsecondthird"
```

or (nice-to-have):

```
"firstCUSTOMSEPARATORsecondCUSTOMSEPARATORthird"
```

(I just wanted to quickly build ad hoc query to verify some postprocessing actually performed by Neo4j consumer and I thought it would be simple but I cannot find any solution. Unlike [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41360603/653539) I want string, not collection, since my issue is in something about length of concatenated string.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using APOC ?

```
UNWIND ['first','second','third'] as c
RETURN apoc.text.join(collect(c), '-') AS concat
```

Where `-` is your custom separator.

Result :

```
╒════════════════════╕
│"concat"            │
╞════════════════════╡
│"first-second-third"│
└────────────────────┘
```

--

**NO APOC**

Take into account when the collection is one element only

```
UNWIND ['first','second','third'] as c
WITH collect(c) AS elts
RETURN CASE WHEN size(elts) > 1 
THEN elts[0] + reduce(x = '', z IN tail(elts) | x + '-' + z)
ELSE elts[0]
END
```

Comment: We don't have APOC installed at the moment so it is not worth installing for ad hoc query. I meant (and prefer) out-of-the box solution, I wonder if it is possible. Anyway apoc.text.join is good point, I am upvoting it.

Comment: APOC functions are shipped by default with recent versions of neo4j.  Anyway, added an example with `reduce` instead

Comment: Thanks for pointing `reduce` function, it works great! I finally simplified `RETURN` clause to `RETURN coalesce(reduce(x = elts[0], z IN tail(elts) | x + '-' + z),'')`. (The `coalesce` function could be omitted if null instead of empty string does not mind or it does not happen in adhoc query with nonempty stream.)

Answer (score 1):

You can further simplify the query as below.  And no need to worry if list is empty and it will return null if l is empty list

```
WITH ['first','second','third'] as l
RETURN REDUCE(s = HEAD(l), n IN TAIL(l) | s + n) AS result
```